# How to adjust the Y Axis maximum value on a bar chart in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: charts, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

How do I change a chart so that the highest values actually are at the top of the chart? Say the chart goes to 1600, but I want it to go to 1500?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the chart creation wizard has been closed, you can change chart elements by accessing a setup window.  Hover over the Y axis until a Y Axis label appears and right click.  The first option is Format Axis.  Click that and you will get a Y Axis setup window.  Scale is the first tab.  For anything you want to change, uncheck Automatic and enter the value you want.  In this case, enter 1500 for Maximum.  If you don't like the grid intervals that are automatically assigned, you can change that, also.  The other tabs give you all kinds of control and fine tuning.  It is a similar process for any element of the chart.